# Inserting HTML in "link name" field of link_to function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm trying to convert an H3 header into a link. Here's the code of it

```
=link_to( "<H3>Home</H3>", root_url)
```

But it literally outputs the "Home" on my page. I'm using haml as view engine. Is there any way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
=link_to(root_url) do
  %h3 Home
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
%h3= link_to("Home", root_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

3rd solution is to use [content_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag)